# Trouble defining a function to use for AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, dom, get

**UPDATE**

After lots of toiling, trouble and help from the community the following link shows the neatest version of the code. http://jsfiddle.net/BPXMw/

==========================================================

Well I seem to be having some real difficulties understanding the order of queues and how they work around AJAX features.

I am currently working on the following script project and have hit a problem. The direct link to the code on JSFiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/gxAr5/15/

```
var shrunk = true;

function studies(caseNumber) {
    $.get("http://<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/includes/functions.php", {

        caseNumber: caseNumber

    }, function(data) {
        $(".expanded span").empty().html(data);
    });
}

function shrink(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    shrunk = false;
    $this = $("#grid li.expanded");

    $this.empty().stop().animate({
        height: '125px',
        left: $this.data('leftPos'),
        top: $this.data('topPos'),
        width: '114px'
    }, 2000, function() {
        shrunk = true;
        $this.css({
            'left': '0',
            'position': 'relative',
            'top': '0',
            'z-index': '0'
        });
        $("#grid li").removeAttr("style");
    });

    $("#grid li").removeAttr("class");
}

$("#grid li").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (shrunk) {
        shrunk = false;

        $(this).addClass("expanded").empty();

        var position = $(this).position();
        $(this).data('leftPos', position.left + 'px');
        $(this).data('topPos', position.top + 'px');

        $(this).css({
            'left': $(this).data('leftPos'),
            'top': $(this).data('topPos'),
            'position': 'absolute',
            'z-index': '2'
        });

        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: '403px',
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            width: '370px'
        }, 2000, studies);
    }
});

$("html").click(function(e) { shrink(e); });
```

The problem lays at the point where the $.get event executes but is unable to pass the param thus returning nothing and does so twice, once as the animation starts and again at the end.

Is there any kind soul out there that would be able to explain as to where I should be defining "studies" so that the param passes please?

Comment: Edited the post to put the code in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there I think the problem lies around here

```
 ...
    }, 2000, function studies(caseNumber) {
$.get("http://<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/includes/functions.php", {
    caseNumber: caseNumber
}, function(data) {
    $(".expanded span").html(data);
});
```

You are declaring the function when you should be referencing it, first define the function:

```
function studies() {
    $.get("http://<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/includes/functions.php", {

            caseNumber: caseNumber

        }, function(data) {
            $(".expanded span").html(data);
        });
}
```

Then call it when the animation completes (you were defining the function on animation complete when you only needed to reference it):

```
 ...
    }, 2000, studies);
```

**UPDATE**

After comments below please find update jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gxAr5/16/

This version you should not be getting the function running twice (I'm not sure what you were doing wrong when you copied the code).

I was also getting FUNCTION_NAME undefined as you were using regular javascript mixed with jQuery and jsfiddle didn't allow me to post functions outside of the jquery scope.  Therefore I modified the html as well so that the text "case1","case2" etc gets passed as an ID and the javascript for handling you clicks on the LI elements is done on the 4th line:

```
$("#grid li").click(function(){
```

I've also substituted the server for Google just so I could get some output and I can see that the variable case number is being passed to google.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You're *calling* `studies` and feeding its return value into the `animate` call, which (as `studies` doesn't *return* a function) is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: I'm doing this off the top of my head - I've updated the code to reflect what you mentioned, 1 thing to note is that I am not passing an argument (caseNumber) now to the function so I would declare it outside of the function so it can be accessed from within the **studies** function

Comment: Sadly that makes the $.get call twice; once at the start of the animation and again at the end, and both times returns false as the param is not defined within the scope.

Comment: Sorry to pester but any ideas on the current problem with the last idea? I hate to have unfinished answers as would like give people ratings. :)

Comment: Sorry this still does not work, caseNumber is still empty and the $.get still attempts to load twice. I guess I will have to wait till I can add a bounty and see if anyone else can attempt to find a solution. Thank you for your attempts.

Comment: Hi just saw this as I saw the answer was accepted, if you have a look using something like firebug you can see the jsfiddle works, the case number is definitely passed... let me know if you see the same results - maybe the problem is in the script that is called pulling the variables?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've put in the question (which I'm not at all sure is the same as the code you originally had in the fiddle), your `studies` function *does* have access to the `caseNumber` var you've declared at the top. But nothing in your code is setting `caseNumber` to anything, and so it will have its default value of `undefined`. Your `$.get` call will therefore miss out the `caseNumber` parameter you're meant to be passing.

There's no reason you should be getting an error that `studies` is undefined with the code you've posted.

Comment: I have again edited the original question to update the text regarding to the explanation. Further to the problem; your correct studies is now defined but as i mentioned to acSlater the code now processes the $.get twice, either side of the animation and the param is still blank as per the original question.

Comment: So the question is "how do I get the onClick attribute value of the <li> element passed through to the AJAX call?